# Make Chrome dragged element display:none

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I discovered something while dealing with drag and drop in Chrome. I want to hide the element after I start dragging it. However, chrome does not allow this and the drag&drop system stops. When I tried it with Firefox, there was no problem. How can I hide the element when dragging starts with Chrome?

```js
var div = document.getElementById("div");

function dragstart(ev) {
  //console.log(ev);
  //console.log(div)
  div.style.display = "none";
}

function dragend(ev) {
  console.log("stop"); // Firefox does not triggers "end". Chrome does.
}
```

```css
#div {
  width: 350px;
  height: 70px;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="div" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart(event)" ondragend="dragend(event)">Drag</div>
```

Comment: Use `div.style.opacity="0"` instead.

Comment: @NathanaelMcDaniel When you use it, drag and drop is canceled when it comes to the area where the element is.

Comment: @KafadanKontak what means: *"to the area where the element is"*? Opacity seems to work quite well. Actually I would expect Chrome's behavior to be the correct one, since it exactly resembles the "click" functionality, in where the "click" event will not fulfill if the elements gains `display: none;` since both mousedown and up are required for that event to fire - and must originate within the same delegated element.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Let's say the item we make opacity is in (0,0) position. When the mouse is in (0,0) position, the drop feature is canceled. I want it to disappear from the screen completely. Even if it disappears on the screen in Firefox, it continues to work.